# Getting the attributes of backbone model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I was wondering how does one get the attributes of a model returned from a server in backkbone

In my model I have this

```
myApp.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
            urlRoot: '/items',

            parse: function(response) {
                response.id = response._id;
                return response;
            }

});
```

In my view I have this

```
   initialize: function() {
                this.model = new myApp.Model();
                this.model.fetch();
            },

            render: function() {
                this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                return this;
            }
```

This is what I have in my template

```
<%- this.model.attributes.age %>
```

For some reason doing the above in template did not yield to any output.

`age` is an attribute from the data that I get back from the server

The template is using underscorejs

Image of data structure from the server
[image]

Comment: Try just `<%= age %>`.  Where does the `template` function come from, underscore?

Comment: yes, the template is from underscore, I will edit my post to reflect that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the attributes themselves to the template function.  Underscore templates by default will use `with` to extend the scope within the function to the passed object, making the properties of the object available by name.

Given that, you'd access `age` simply with:

```
<%= age %>
```

Comment: Hmmm, that did not seem to do the trick, I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: age is not defined`

Comment: If you inspect the attribute of the model prior to rendering, do you see `age`?  e.g. `console.log(this.model.attributes)`

Comment: Did anything change?  Honestly your first template *should have* worked, as setting the template function to a property of the view should have caused `this` to refer to the view during the template render.  It's just not the typical usage.